# Using a Delete query on a single table when referencing other tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint, sql-delete

I want to run a delete query to remove certain data from a table in a Sharepoint list using an MS Access query. However I want to be sure only to delete from a single list based on the values of another table.

The table is TMainData: This consists solely of number fields that are references to the keyfields in other tables, such as TProgram which has a program name, or TContact which has the point of contact, or TPositionTitle which has a title like Site Director.

So a TMainData entry looks something like
 ProgramID, which links to TPrograms: 4
 ContactID, which links to TContacts: 42
 PositionTitle, which links to TPositionTitle: 3

This tells me that the Site Director (TPositionTitle 3) of Anesthesiology (ProgramID 4) is John Smith (ContactID 42).

Here's where it gets tricky: I have a reference under TPrograms to TProgramType. I want to delete all records under TMainData where they link to a certain Program Type, because that program type is going away. HOWEVER... I don't want to delete the program itself (yet), just the lines referencing that program in TMainData.

The "manual" way I see to do this is to run queries that identify what the ProgramIDs are of the programs I want to delete the contacts for, and then use those IDs in a delete query that only references the TMainData query. I'm wondering if there's a way to use referential data, because I may have to be running some ridiculous update queries at a later time that would need this same info.

I dug through https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-queries-to-delete-one-or-more-records-from-a-database-A323BF1A-C9B4-4C86-8719-BE58BDF1B10C but it doesn't seem to cover deleting from one table based on values referenced in another table.

Comment: How many program IDs? Create a query joining tables so the Program Type can be viewed. Then consider: `DELETE FROM query WHERE [Program Type] IN (7, 11, 28, 35)`

Comment: I hadn't considered using multiple queries, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2):

You already seem to understand what you need to do to achieve the desired result when you state:

> ...run queries that identify what the `ProgramIDs` are of the programs I want to delete the contacts for, and then use those IDs in a delete query that only references the `TMainData` query.

If I've understood your description correctly, I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
delete from tmaindata
where 
tmaindata.programid in
(
    select tprograms.programid 
    from tprograms 
    where tprograms.tprogramtype = 'YourProgramType'
)
```

Always take a backup of your data before running `delete` queries - there is no undo.

Comment: I think I get it. So if I had to do the selection based on a property referenced in TPrograms,

Comment: I think so. I was trying to convey that if the relevant records in TPrograms are based on a lookup value in TPrograms to a third, which references a fourth table, I just need to build that linkage into the SQL of the select. So long as the "delete from" only lists TMainData, it won't do that 'referential integrity' delete. Is that correct?

Comment: @RobertPatrician Yes, you are correct - you can build on the `select` subquery which obtains the appropriate `programid` values and the `delete` query will remain valid since here is no ambiguity surrounding which table the records are to be deleted from.